# listdll doesn't see assemblies loaded

Tags: .net, clr, sysinternals

I was pretty sure that the .NET runtime loads assemblies as ordinary dlls. But I found that when I connect "native" debugger to the managed process - I don't see the assemblies loaded.

The same thing applies to Sysinternals tool - listdll. It sees only dlls loaded, not assemblies.

I wonder how the CLR loads and executes the code from assemblies?
I there a tool similar to listdll to go over all managed processes and list all loaded assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, an assembly isn't a DLL. A DLL is a physical file, while an assembly is a logical concept of the .NET framework. A single DLL may contain several assemblies.

There are many ways to list the assemblies loaded by a process, here are some of them:

1. Using SysInternals Process Explorer, double-click the process and switch to the .NET Assemblies tab.
2. Using a debugger like WinDbg/CDB/NTSD, attach to the target process, load the SOS extension by entering the command `.loadby sos clr`, then enter the `!DumpDomain` command to list the assemblies loaded into each AppDomain
3. Using the [MDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mdbg-exe) debugger, attach to the target process, then enter the command `list assemblies`